# Getting security information for remote registry keys?

Tags: windows, security, winapi, registry, advapi32

According to the [documentation for API function `GetNamedSecurityInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446645%28VS.85%29.aspx), it can get information from the following objects:

- Local or remote files or directories on an NTFS file system
- Local or remote printers
- Local or remote Windows services
- Network shares
- Registry keys
- Semaphores, events, mutexes, and waitable timers
- File-mapping objects
- Directory service objects

But what I need is to get information from a registry key on a **remote** computer. Can `GetNamedSecurityInfo` obtain that somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can. Just pass the name of the key.

```
\\ComputerName\CLASSES_ROOT\SomePath
```

Format of object names are described in the [documentation for SE_OBJECT_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379593%28VS.85%29.aspx) enumeration. Note that there are some caveats related to authentication/authorization, read the documentation for [RegConnectRegistry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724840%28VS.85%29.aspx) as well.